# Why the various definitions of the thin space \,?

Tags: spacing, amsmath

Knuths definition of `\,` is `\mskip\thinmuskip`.

LaTeX changes this definition to

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\,}{%
   \relax\ifmmode\mskip\thinmuskip\else\thinspace\fi
}
\def\thinspace{\kern .16667em }
```

`amsmath.sty` says it's

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tmspace}[3]{%
  \ifmmode\mskip#1#2\else\kern#1#3\fi\relax}
\renewcommand{\,}{\tmspace+\thinmuskip{.1667em}}
```

I might understand LaTeX's point to make a command usable also in text mode. But what's the point of the redefinition by amsmath?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should look at the full picture:

```latex
 152   │ \ifx\leavevmode@ifvmode\@undefined
 153   │ \DeclareRobustCommand{\tmspace}[3]{%
 154   │   \ifmmode\mskip#1#2\else\kern#1#3\fi\relax}
 155   │ \else
 156   │ \DeclareRobustCommand{\tmspace}[3]{%
 157   │   \ifmmode\mskip#1#2\else\leavevmode@ifvmode\kern#1#3\fi\relax}
 158   │ \fi
 159   │ \renewcommand{\,}{\tmspace+\thinmuskip{.1667em}}
 160   │ \let\thinspace\,
 161   │ \renewcommand{\!}{\tmspace-\thinmuskip{.1667em}}
 162   │ \let\negthinspace\!
 163   │ \renewcommand{\:}{\tmspace+\medmuskip{.2222em}}
 164   │ \let\medspace\:
 165   │ \newcommand{\negmedspace}{\tmspace-\medmuskip{.2222em}}
 166   │ \renewcommand{\;}{\tmspace+\thickmuskip{.2777em}}
 167   │ \let\thickspace\;
 168   │ \newcommand{\negthickspace}{\tmspace-\thickmuskip{.2777em}}
```

The two definitions of `\tmspace` are due to recent decisions to make such commands start paragraph mode anyway. With a recent LaTeX kernel the second one will be used.

Contrast this with the code in the LaTeX kernel:

```latex
1619   │ \DeclareRobustCommand{\,}{%
1620   │    \relax\ifmmode\mskip\thinmuskip\else\thinspace\fi
1621   │ }

1630   │ \def\thinspace{\leavevmode@ifvmode\kern .16667em }
1631   │ \def\negthinspace{\leavevmode@ifvmode\kern-.16667em }

4543   │ \def\>{\mskip\medmuskip}
4544   │ \def\;{\mskip\thickmuskip}
4545   │ \def\!{\mskip-\thinmuskip}

4547   │ \let\:=\>
```

The approach of `amsmath` is much more rational and cleaner. They also provide text mode equivalent of all macros, whereas `\!` cannot be used in text mode if `amsmath` is not loaded, and similarly for the others. The final result will be essentially the same. However, a `\,` command will be translated into `\tmspace+\thinmuskip{.1667em}` when written in an auxiliary file, instead of `\,`. Not really a big deal.